# Orientation change colapsing children in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, orientation, expandablelistview, childviews

I have created a `ExpandableListView`.

When I expanded it,  its children are showing properly.

But when I change the orientation from `potrait` to `lanscape` or vice-versa the `ExpandableListView` remains open but its children are not showing. After clicking the layout they are showing properly..

Any answers will help me.

Comment: try  declaring in the AndroidManifest.xml android:configChanges="orientation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the device is rotated, the app is restarted. So onSaveInstance is called before the app gets destroyed.

You can **save the expandable list adapter in onSaveInstance** and when the onCreate is finally called when the app is started again, you can retrieve the Expandable list adapter and set it to the list view.